# In Fortran, the unit in the write function is character. How to understand this?

Tags: fortran, character

`character(len=10240), public :: line`  
​`write(line, '(a)') '******'` 
I come across the above code. I am confused as to why the unit in the `write` function is a character type?  Shouldn't it be a number? Where does it print to in this case?

Comment: This is an write operation to an "internal file" in fortran lingo. That means, you can write formatted text into a string character

Answer (score 3):

This snippet uses a Fortran feature known as "[Internal Files](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/data-and-i-o/fortran-i-o/internal-files-and-scratch-files.html)".

An internal file is a scalar variable of type `character` (or a character substring, or character array).

> Why the unit in the write function is a character type? Shouldn't it be a number?

To operate on a internal file, instead of specifying a unit number for the READ or WRITE statement, use the name of the variable as the file specifier.

> Where does it print to in this case?

It prints into the character variable itself, as if it was a text file.

With this feature, you can, for example, write formatted text into a character variable, and use all the formatting features present in Fortran.

Comment: I use this feature to convert integer to character and vice versa